# Is "You are good than him" somehow grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence

Is "You are good than him" somehow grammatically correct? I know that the indisputable sentence is "You are better than him". But still wanted to know if the former is correct in some context.

Comment: *Is "You are good than him" somehow grammatically correct? "* No.

Comment: Is there any argument for thinking that it might be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Than him” implies a comparison. The comparative forms of *good* are *better* and *best*. It is ungrammatical not use the comparative when it has been promised by “than”. In this case with two to compare, *better* is the correct choice. I see no escape from this analysis and cannot imagine circumstances where we could say “You are good than him.”

Comment: Is there an unabridged version of any dictionary where it is mentioned that "good" can be used in comparative?

Comment: @NSR I can't imagine that there is, I've been hearing English for 70 years and I've never come across it. I'd also like to point that though, as Anton rightly says, the comparative forms of 'good' are 'better' and 'best' you can't use the superlative best with 'than' because it's an absolute rather than a more equal comparison. That is you can't say "You are best than him."

Comment: @BoldBen Thanks :-)